# reshape a column into 2 columns

Tags: python, twitter

I have twitter data extracted in the following form:

```
%23WinterClassic
31228
%23NewYearsDay
80094
%23OutbackBowl
None
%23PeachBowl
None
%23CitrusBowl
None
%22Bruce+Arians%22
11614
Lingard
65684
```

I used the following script to generate the above data:

```
usaTrendingTopics="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=23424977"
response, data=client.request(usaTrendingTopics)
tweets=json.loads(data)
for i in tweets:
    for j in i['trends']:
        for k, v in j.iteritems():
            keys=['query','tweet_volume']
            if k in keys:
                print v
```

I want to avoid using third-party wrappers like 'twitter' for learning purposes.

I want the data in the following format

```
trending_topic, trending_topic_volume
%23WinterClassic, 31228
%23NewYearsDay, 80094
%23OutbackBowl. None
%23PeachBowl,None
%23CitrusBowl,None
%22Bruce+Arians%22,11614
Lingard,65684
```

It must be really simple to convert the single column into two columns.  Any thoughts or help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if k == 'query':
    print v + ', ',
elif k == 'tweet_volume':
    print v
```